# Deprecated Facebook login permissions

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-permissions

My app integrates Facebook login with the following permissions :user_education_history and user_work_history. The app was working just fine until today morning when I attempt to login I get the following error:

invalid scopes: user_education_history, user_work_history. This message is only shown to developers other app users will ignore these permissions if present.

I went through the docs and I discovered that they were deprecated on the 4th of this month but I cannot seem to find the new permissions for the education and the work history ... any help ?

Comment: there is no new permission. it´s not possible anymore to get it.

Comment: @luschn No way to get the user's education and employment info anymore ?

Comment: no. if there would be an alternative, it would be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @luschn why would they block access to such information ... many apps are operating over this kind of stuff !!

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: in case you missed it, read about the cambridge analytica scandal. that´s why.

Comment: @luschn yea I figured that would be the reason but why deprecate access to some information and leave the some other !!

Comment: my guess is that those data fields were not used very often, or just to get the data and store it in a database, without really using it. that is why facebook decided to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook is removing access to a lot of things as a result of recent negative press surrounding data mining of their users.  In almost all cases the information is simply no longer available, there is no alternative method to access it.

More information is available in the Facebook developer blog:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates

Note that the message you mention is only shown to Facebook accounts with developer credentials.  Regular Facebook users don't see this message and the Facebook API simply ignores requests for scopes which are no longer allowed.  If the data being requested are optional in the context of the app, you should create a test Facebook account and see how it behaves when requesting the data doesn't return anything (or causes unexpected errors).